# Java-8: boolean primitive array to stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

There is no nice way to convert given `boolean[] foo` array into stream in Java-8 **in one statement**, or I am missing something?

<strike>(I will not ask *why?*, but it is really incomprehensible: why not add stream support for all primitive types?)</strike>

**Hint:** `Arrays.stream(foo)` will not work, there is no such method for `boolean[]` type.

Comment: Indeed, Java 8 only provides specialized primitive streams for `int`, `long` and `double`, and `Arrays.stream` does not accept a `boolean[]`. I guess you will have to box it.

Comment: Would using a [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) be of benefit here instead of using an array?

Comment: @JonK I think the point is to be able to do stream-operations on it. Can you do that on BitSet?

Comment: @Fildor Yes you can - but because I don't know exactly what the OP is trying to do I couldn't say if a BitSet would be better suited here. I just left it there as a possible alternative and the OP can decide whether or not it would actually be useful

Comment: @Fildor: yes, you can do stream operations on a bit set. The result, however, might be different, as you are streaming over the bits (i.e. their positional number) then. Surprisingly, the obstacles are on the other side: there is no concise way to convert a `boolean[]` array to a `BitSet`.

Comment: @Holger Over the posNumber - of course! Didn't think of that. Moving around in C# world _and_ Java, Java Streams still give me headaches ...

Comment: Hope, that linked Q&A still helps. Creating `BooleanStream` would also imply the creation of `PrimitiveIterator.OfBoolean`, `OptionalBoolean`, `BooleanFunction<T>`, `BooleanPredicate` (or do we abuse `BooleanUnaryFunction` for that?), `BooleanBinaryOperator`, `BooleanToIntFunction`, `BooleanToLongFunction`, `BooleanToDoubleFunction`, `BooleanConsumer`, (for some unknown reason, `BooleanSupplier` exists), `ObjBooleanConsumer`, `BooleanSummaryStatistics`, etc.

Comment: @Holger, BooleanSupplier completes the matrix of `(Object|int|long|double|void) -> (Object|int|long|double|void|boolean)` functions: all 30 of these actually exist in JDK, and no other one/zero argument functions seems to be provided. So `BooleanSupplier` looks reasonable.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: that’s not convincing, as this kind of matrix is arbitrary, i.e. there is no `boolean` on the input side, because all other types producing a `boolean` are predicates, which `BooleanSupplier` is not. When it comes to types like `ObjIntConsumer`, there is no symmetry either. Their existence is much better explained by the fact, that they are actually needed by the provided API. In contrast, the type `BooleanSupplier` is not used at all.

Comment: it is interesting how author had to cross out his question __WHY__ jdk designers decided not to deal with booleans :) . i came to this SO question being puzzled precisely by the _inconsistent design_ of JDK std lib. So question __WHY__ is still valid.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Given `boolean[] foo` use

```
Stream<Boolean> stream = IntStream.range(0, foo.length)
                                  .mapToObj(idx -> foo[idx]);
```

Note that every boolean value will be boxed, but it's usually not a big problem as boxing for boolean does not allocate additional memory (just uses one of predefined values - `Boolean.TRUE` or `Boolean.FALSE`).

Comment: In your opinion, would it be safe to infer that the "lightweight" boxing operations on `boolean`s may be the reason why there are no specialized primitive streams for `boolean`s?

Comment: Nice one +1, let's see, may be other ideas will come into people minds :)

Comment: @Mena, there are multiple reasons. One of them is code blow-up: every primitive stream adds a big amount of specialized code, not to mention quadratic API grow when you add `IntStream.mapToBoolean`, `BooleanStream.mapToDouble` and so on. So they had to stop somewhere. They considered that `int`, `long` and `double` are the most useful primitive types, so it was a reasonable tradeoff. Hopefully Java 10 will bring us generic specialization and `Stream<boolean>` will work out of the box.

Comment: Close as you can get, I guess. But "nice" is different - IMHO. (+1)

Comment: @TagirValeev They could have stopped at ... all of the primitives, there aren't that many (8 primitives + 1 for references).

Answer (score 12):

You can use [Guava's `Booleans` class](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Booleans.html#asList-boolean...-):

```
Stream<Boolean> stream = Booleans.asList(foo).stream();
```

This is a pretty efficient way because `Booleans.asList` returns a wrapper for the array and does not make any copies.

Comment: Nice! Note though that the resulting stream will not be SIZED unless custom spliterator is defined (and it's [not defined](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/0fd20594150e5493138e83462b25b81db2507f49/guava/src/com/google/common/primitives/Booleans.java#L382). This might impact the performance of some operations like `toArray()`. Also it will not parallelize great (if somebody cares).

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: the [default spliterator of `List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#spliterator--) “reports Spliterator.SIZED and Spliterator.ORDERED”…

Comment: @TagirValeev I've just checked the characteristics of the spliterator returned by `Booleans.asList()` and it looks like it has a SIZED charateristic.

Comment: @Holger, sorry, my bad. Then the only problem is parallelism. Though it's also [addressed](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8158365) in Java-9.

Comment: @TagirValeev What is the problem with parallelism? I thought the SIZED characteristic is enough for good parallelism, isn't?

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov, nope, spliterator `trySplit()` method must be properly implemented. Default is "poor man parallelism" which traverses list sequentially via iterator into intermediate buffers

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: funny, we have such a `Spliterator` in our code base for years now, but I’m afraid when Java 9 is released, it will not only be obsolete because there will be an appropriate default spliterator, but also because there is little likelihood to encounter a random access list without custom spliterator anymore. I once thought about a `ListIterator` based improvement for non-random access lists, but who uses them anyway…

Answer (score 2):

*of course you could create a stream directly*

```
Stream.Builder<Boolean> builder = Stream.builder();
for (int i = 0; i < foo.length; i++)
  builder.add(foo[i]);
Stream<Boolean> stream = builder.build();
```

*…or by wrapping an* `AbstractList` *around* foo

```
Stream<Boolean> stream = new AbstractList<Boolean>() {
  public Boolean get(int index) {return (foo[index]);}
  public int size() {return foo.length;}
}.stream();
```

Comment: That's three top-level statements + three statement-expressions inside of the `for`. ,_________,

Comment: @Andrey I don't have the phrase to put it another way. *Direct* is meant in the sense of *being put together manually piece by piece*. I hope You like solution two more.

Answer (score 1):

Skimming through the early access JavaDoc (ie. [`java.base`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk15/docs/api/java.base/module-summary.html) module) of the newest [java-15](/questions/tagged/java-15), there is *still no neat way* to make the primitive boolean array work with Stream API together well. There is *no new feature* in the API with treating a primitive boolean array since [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8).

Note that there exist [`IntStream`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html), [`DoubleStream`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html) and [`LongStream`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/LongStream.html), but nothing like `BooleanStream` that would represent of a variation of a sequence of primitive booleans. Also the overloaded methods of `Stream` are [`Stream::mapToInt`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)), [`Stream::mapToDouble`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToDouble(java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction)) and [`Stream::mapToLong`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToLong(java.util.function.ToLongFunction)), but not `Stream::mapToBoolean` returning such hypothetical `BooleanStream`.

Oracle seems to keep following this pattern, which could be found also in [`Collectors`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html). There is also no such support for `float` primitives (there is for `double` primitives instead). In my opinion, unlike of `float`, the `boolean` support would make sense to implement.

Back to the code... if you have a boxed boolean array (ie. `Boolean[] array`), the things get easier:

```
Boolean[] array = ...
Stream<Boolean> streamOfBoxedBoolean1 = Arrays.stream(array);
Stream<Boolean> streamOfBoxedBoolean2 = Stream.of(array);
```

Otherwise you have to use *more than one statement* as said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42225051/3764965) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42225354/3764965) answer.

However, you asked (*emphasizes mine*):

> way to convert given `boolean[]` foo array into stream in Java-8 in **one** statement.

... there is actually a way to achieve this through **one statement** using a `Spliterator` made from an `Iterator`. It is definetly not nice but :

```
boolean[] array = ...

Stream<Boolean> stream = StreamSupport.stream(
        Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(
                new Iterator<>() {
                    int index = 0;
                    @Override public boolean hasNext() { return index < array.length; }
                    @Override public Boolean next() { return array[index++]; }
                }, 0), false);
```