# Generate stream of Boolean

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How do you create stream of `Boolean.FALSE`, say, length of 100?

What I've struggled with is:

1. Originally I've intended to create an array of `Boolean.FALSE`. But `new Boolean[100]` returns an array of `NULL`. So reasonably I considered to use stream API as a convenient `Iterable` and almost ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160081/why-is-an-array-not-assignable-to-iterable)) `Iterable` manipulation tool;
2. There is no `Boolean` no-params constructor ([2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html)), hence I can't
   use `Stream.generate()`, since it accepts `Supplier<T>` ([3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)).

What I found is `Stream.iterate(Boolean.FALSE, bool -> Boolean.FALSE).limit(100);` gives what I want, but it doesn't seem to be quite elegant solution, IMHO.

One more option, I found ([4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225001/java-8-boolean-primitive-array-to-stream)) is `IntStream.range(0, 100).mapToObj(idx -> Boolean.FALSE);`, which seems to me even more strange.

Despite these options don't violate pipeline conception of a stream API, are there any more concise ways to create stream of `Boolean.FALSE`?

Comment: Why do you think you cannot use `Stream.generate()`? Try this: `Stream.generate(() -> Boolean.FALSE).limit(100)`

Comment: I can’t imagine any reasonable use case for such a stream. If you follow the recommended usage of only using stateless functions, i.e. do not depend on the processing order, the result can always only be a stream of hundred identical elements or an empty stream. Whatever the final result will be, it would always be possible to generate it from a single element stream instead.

Comment: @Holger I detect cycles on undirected graph. One of the steps needs to be performed is detection of parallel edges. I mark every vertex I visited to detect parallelism. So each vertex has a match in the array of "is visited". After the iteration is completed, the array of "is visited" should be reset. And here I let such a stream play. I could use an array of 0 and 1 for this purpose, but for clarity sake decided to use what I used.

Comment: Thanks for trying to explain, but I still can’t image, how you want to use 100 `false` constants in a useful way. You are talking about an array in your explanation, but a stream is not an array. It doesn’t work like an array. In that regard, it didn’t matter if you used a stream of 100 zeros as starting point, they were as meaningless as 100 `false` constants. If you need a boolean array initialized with `false`, you could create it as easy as `new boolean[100]` without the need for a stream.

Comment: @Holger the exact reason I decided to use a stream is my may be naive intention to iterate over the array with its help. As you precisely noticed, and I totally agree with you, I could simply use `new boolean[100]`. And then iterate through it with a loop. But a big question still floats in my mind. When is it worthwhile to prefer a stream over a loop to iterate through things?)

Comment: That’s not easy to answer, you’ll need some experience to decide. And not everyone will have the same opinion. As a rule of thumb, if the processing of each element is independent from each other (or its position) and the resulting code is simpler than the loop’s code or allows to do more complex things (in an easy way) than before. Or if there’s a reasonable expectation to get a benefit from parallel processing (which makes independence of the processing order even more important).

Comment: If this is all to initialize an array to a value, you can just use [`java.util.Arrays.fill`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-), no streams necessary. `Arrays.fill(array, Boolean.FALSE);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even though `Boolean` has no no-arg constructor, you can still use `Stream.generate` using a lambda:

```
Stream.generate(() -> Boolean.FALSE).limit(100)
```

This also has the advantage (compared to using a constructor) that those will be *the same* `Boolean` instances, and not 100 different but equal ones.

Comment: OMG! Sure! I completely forgot about lambdas thinking about method references... Thx

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Collections`'s `static <T> List<T> nCopies(int n, T o)`:

```
Collections.nCopies (100, Boolean.FALSE).stream()...
```

Note that the `List` returned by `nCopies` is `tiny (it contains a single reference to the data object).`, so it doesn't require more storage compared to the `Stream.generate().limit()` solution, regardless of the required size.

Answer (score 1):

*of course you could create the stream directly*

```
Stream.Builder<Boolean> builder = Stream.builder();
for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
  builder.add( false );
Stream<Boolean> stream = builder.build();
```